# Prove or disprove $\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{\infty} \prod_{k=0}^{i}\prod_{l=0}^{j} a_k^*a_l\right) - a_0^*a_0 \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $(a_i)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that

$$ \sum_{i,j=0}^{\infty} \prod_{k=0}^{i}\prod_{l=0}^{j} a_k^*a_l$$ converges unconditionally. Also, it is rather apparent that the limit is then a positive element.

My question is now: Is it true or false that the following inequality holds

$$ \left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{\infty} \prod_{k=0}^{i}\prod_{l=0}^{j} a_k^*a_l\right) - a_0^*a_0 \ge 0 ?$$

The only thing that came to my mind were basic (counter-)examples and manipulations, but they did not lead me anywhere.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: What $a^*$ means?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Probably you know the answer to my question:    http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2172968/254463   Thanks!